# Redux Toolkit state doesn't update even after adding extraReducers

Tags: redux-toolkit

I have a very limited understanding of the redux toolkit compared to its previous version. I am struggling to understand why isn't my state getting updated on the trigger of getUsers.

I have added the `extraReducers` as well.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { fetchSample } from './filterAPI';

export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  'primaryFilters/getUsers',
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log(getState, dispatch);
    const response = await fetchSample();
    return response;
  }
);

const primaryFiltersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'primaryFilters',
  initialState: {
    dateFilter: {
      dates: {
        key: 'selection',
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
      },
      dummyData: null,
    },
    status: null,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUsers.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.dummyData = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
      });
  },
});

export default primaryFiltersSlice.reducer;
```

Here's fetchSample function:

```
export const fetchSample = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  return response.json();
};
```

**Additionally, I want to point out that my status is triggering from pending to idle and so on but my actual state isn't updating.**

Here's the screenshot for the same:

[image]

I would also like to know how can we log the messages within those extraReducers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I am able to dispatch actions by keeping the status update at the bottom instead of the top. I would love to have a better explanation for the same, here's what exactly fixed my code:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { fetchSample } from './filterAPI';

export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  'primaryFilters/getUsers',
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log(getState, dispatch);
    const response = await fetchSample();
    return response;
  }
);

// export const updateDates = () => {

// }

const primaryFiltersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'primaryFilters',
  initialState: {
    dateFilter: {
      dates: {
        key: 'selection',
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
      },
      dummyData: null,
    },
    status: null,
  },
  reducer: {
    updateDate: (state, action) => {
      console.log('Actions = ', action);
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUsers.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.dummyData = action.payload;
        state.status = 'idle';
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
      });
  },
});

export default primaryFiltersSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, looking at your data structure, you probably want to update `state.dateFilter.dummyData`, not `state.dummyData` - at least assuming you want to match your `initialState` structure.

Also, `createAsyncThunk` does not take a callback `dispatch, getState`:
correct would be

```
export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  'primaryFilters/getUsers',
  async (arg, {dispatch, getState}) => {
```

(but that does not make a difference here since you are using neither)

As for logging... just `console.log`? Or do you mean you are getting a Proxz object? In that case `console.log(current(state))`